# Premiere Pro media linking with illegal filenames

Tags: premiere, video-editor, adobe, file-formats, premiere-pro

I was working on a video project with some classmates and after our class ended I asked our editor if I could have the footage. She everso-nicely renamed the files so they are human-readable, however, included `/` in many of the files. For example, `scene2_shot17_take1-OTS/chairs.MP4` is the name of a file. Mac, for some reason, is able to read the `/`. Windows, however, reads it as `scene2_shot17_take1-OTSchairs.MP4`.

For Premiere Pro, when I load up the project, it asks me to locate all of the files. It says the last path was `Path/to/file/scene2_shot17_take1-OTS:chairs.MP4`. So instead of replacing `/` with ``, it replaces it with `:` which is also an illegal character to have in filenames!

I've used [Advanced Renamer](https://www.advancedrenamer.com/) to rename all the files that contain `` to `_`. My only question now is how to inform premier pro that I have made that change. I have almost 100 files that had `/` in them and I would not like to have to manually link them all. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some STRUGGLE. I found this worked (strap in for a ride). Here's the step-by-step:

1. (Since I was in a group) have your project open and go to `Edit>Team Project>Convert Team Project to Project`.
2. The Premiere Pro project file (.prproj) is actually a compressed XML file. Exit Premiere Pro and then rename your project file from `YourProject.prproj` to `YourProject.zip`
3. unzip the file. It wouldn't work on my computer unless I used 7-zip to unzip it.
4. open the file titled `YourProject` in a text editor (I used VSCode)
5. Access the find and replace functionality (here's where it gets complicated)
6. Some text/code editors have an option like [`regular expression`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) or [`use regex`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). You will need to enable this.
7. input `([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.-]+):([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.-]+)\.MP4` for the `find` field. this finds any `.MP4` file that contains `:`
8. input `$1_$2.MP4` in the `replace` field. `$1` is all the text before `:` and `$2` is all the text after up until `.MP4`.
9. Hit replace all and save the file- make sure to add the `.prproj` extension to it.
10. Load it up!

remember to always make a backup of your project file as I've only tested this a little bit. It worked for me!